# how to plot member of object with different color?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i want to plot  this python object using matplotlib. this object has three different labels i want to plot each label with different color

```
{1.0: [[-1.9242, 1.0], [-2.0039, 1.0], [-2.0259, 1.0], [-1.8096, 1.0], [-1.9083, 1.0]],
 2.0: [[0.53616, 2.0], [0.56647, 2.0], [0.50042, 2.0], [0.31371, 2.0], [0.61207, 2.0], [0.93016, 2.0], [0.27571, 2.0], [0.14968, 2.0], [0.2886, 2.0], [0.3646, 2.0]], 
 3.0: [[1.1139, 3.0], [1.1449, 3.0], [1.5837, 3.0], [1.7038, 3.0], [1.192, 3.0], [1.6529, 3.0], [1.3052, 3.0], [2.2981, 3.0], [1.3196, 3.0], [1.3439, 3.0], [1.3795, 3.0], [1.5595, 3.0], [1.6977, 3.0], [1.2672, 3.0], [1.4191, 3.0], [1.719, 3.0], [1.6339, 3.0], [1.4335, 3.0], [1.4942, 3.0], [1.574, 3.0]]}
```

Comment: You need to tell which part of your 'object' should be where on the graph and what part of the object is the 'label'. Also What have you already tried to accomplish this and where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can just issue separate plot statements specifying the [color](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) with `c=...`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

d = {1.0: [[-1.9242, 1.0], [-2.0039, 1.0], [-2.0259, 1.0], [-1.8096, 1.0], [-1.9083, 1.0]],
 2.0: [[0.53616, 2.0], [0.56647, 2.0], [0.50042, 2.0], [0.31371, 2.0], [0.61207, 2.0], [0.93016, 2.0], [0.27571, 2.0], [0.14968, 2.0], [0.2886, 2.0], [0.3646, 2.0]], 
 3.0: [[1.1139, 3.0], [1.1449, 3.0], [1.5837, 3.0], [1.7038, 3.0], [1.192, 3.0], [1.6529, 3.0], [1.3052, 3.0], [2.2981, 3.0], [1.3196, 3.0], [1.3439, 3.0], [1.3795, 3.0], [1.5595, 3.0], [1.6977, 3.0], [1.2672, 3.0], [1.4191, 3.0], [1.719, 3.0], [1.6339, 3.0], [1.4335, 3.0], [1.4942, 3.0], [1.574, 3.0]]}
plt.scatter(*zip(*d[1.]), c='b')
plt.scatter(*zip(*d[2.]), c='r')
plt.scatter(*zip(*d[3.]), c='g')
plt.show()
```